# GCC auto-vectorizer and class member memory alignment

Tags: gcc, arm, vectorization, compiler-optimization, memory-alignment

I'm running into a weird issue with GCC auto-vecorization: It works fine when I use local variables in a function, but not when I use class members instead.

Here's a very simple piece of code that shows the problem. This code vectorizes without issues:

```
__attribute__((aligned(64))) float afloat[409600];
afloat input;

for (int c=0; c<409600; c++)
{
    input[c] = 1;
}
```

Now if I move `afloat input` to the class definition, the code either won't vectorize, or multiple variants of the code are generated based on alignment checks.

I'm trying to make some pretty heavy code work on a Raspberry Pi 3 (GCC 5.2.1, ARM Cortex A53), and even for some pretty simple code where I use a few arrays, it reports that it's generating 9 different versions of it (and none seems to be vectorized); when using local variables I only get 1 version which is vectorized. Unfortunately I cannot use local variables...

I'm guessing here, but what I think is happening is that for local variables, gcc knows where it allocates them on the stack so it knows how they are aligned. For class members, even though gcc should be able to tell how they are aligned respective to each other, gcc can't know if the class itself is aligned on a 16-byte boundary. (I'm taking care of that by overriding new, but obviously gcc doesn't 'see' that). In the Intel IPP compiler that I normally use on Windows, `#pragma vector aligned` solves this.

So, my question is: How do I make gcc generate optimized (vectorized) code in this case? I have several hundreds of these, so manually writing NEON code isn't really an option. I've tried using __builtin_assume_aligned - both on the variables that I'm using and even on the this pointer - but that didn't help. I'm guessing that if I could somehow tell gcc that the class is aligned properly, it should be able to determine how the variables are aligned, but I don't think that that's possible?

Comment: It would help if you actually posted a compilable example where you expect vectorization but don't get it.

Comment: I can try, but the behavior on ARM and Intel is different so it would be difficult to test for most people. On Windows the same code actually does vectorize (although 9 other paths are generated as well).

But in general it seems pretty clear what happens: If you use a class member, gcc can't decide if it's aligned and will either generate multiple paths or not vectorize at all.

Comment: It's probably worth saying what exact build of GCC you're seeing this with (and maybe trying others) - unless it's pure FSF trunk, be aware that most people release their own version with their own magic patches on top, and not all builds are equal.

Comment: Well, I've seen it in the gcc that's included in Ubuntu MATE for Raspberry Pi 2/3 (I can't look at the -v info right now because I'm not in my office), but I've seen similar behavior on Windows for MinGW 4.8.1 - it *does* vectorize the same code but it still generates a lot of (unnecessary) alternative paths for alignments that can never occur. So to me it really looks like something is missing in gcc's alignment analysis, both versions do what they should for local variables but not for class members.